# How and what CMS package to integrate with a .NET website

Tags: .net, content-management-system

I am looking to develop a website mostly consisting of static pages.  I need to provide the ability to allow the site owners to be able to log on to an administrative section of the site and update the content (text, links, images etc) themselves.  I am most likely going to develop the site using .NET.  Can anyone recommend an open source CMS package that will easily integrate with .NET or some jquery.plugin etc.  I have no previous experience in providing CMS features to a web site and will welcome all feedback

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download and install the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), there are a few there which you can easily download.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you download the Web Platform Installer from Microsoft and have a look at what's there? It's got a few nice, free CMSs that you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

Any below should work:

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)

[N2](http://n2cms.com/)

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) - based on MVC